# How to manipulate a content variable from inside struct's function?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. I followed the tutorial from [their doc here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html). In Listing 5-13, we have an implementation of struct that prints an area.

My question is how to manipulate `self.width` or `self.height` from within the struct's function, such as this to be possible:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }

    // I need to use mut self instead of &self so I can access self variable here
    // but since I pass the ownership into this function, the prinln! 
    // throws an error: "value borrowed here after move"
    // but If I don't do that, the set_width cannot manipulate the width
    fn set_width(mut self, width: u32) {
        self.width = width;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: 30,
        height: 50,
    };

   rect1.set_width(50);
   
   // value borrowed here after move error 
   println!("The area of the rectangle is {} square pixels.", rect1.area());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking `self`, whether by `mut` or not, means the method *consumes* self. If you want to *modify* the structure in-place, you need `&mut self`. In fact this is covered by the text below 5.13:

> We’ve chosen `&self` here for the same reason we used `&Rectangle` in the function version: we don’t want to take ownership, and we just want to read the data in the struct, not write to it. **If we wanted to change the instance that we’ve called the method on as part of what the method does, we’d use `&mut self` as the first parameter**. Having a method that takes ownership of the instance by using just `self` as the first parameter is rare; this technique is usually used when the method transforms self into something else and you want to prevent the caller from using the original instance after the transformation.

(emphasis mine)

`&mut` having been covered by the previous [section 4.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references).

`self` is both magical and not, it's syntactic sugar for a variation of `self: <something>Self`, and allows calling the method on an instance (`inst.method()`), but that aside it follows the normal Rust rule with respect to ownership and borrowing.

Comment: Thank you but when I use `&mut self` as the first parameter. It throws "cannot borrow `rect1` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable". I'm kinda confused with ownership concept here.

Comment: oh... I see... I need to change the `let rect1 = Rectangle {....}` into `let mut rect1 = Rectangle {.....}`. Not having the `mut` attribute means it is a immutable both from "inside" method or outside of the struct.